# Change scrot output directory

Tags: lubuntu, directory, scrot-command

When using `scrot`, I'd like to have the files appear in `~/Pictures/Screenshots/` instead of in my home directory.

---

```
scrot -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/Screenshots/'
```

works OK, but I would love not to have to use the `-e` flag because I want to have the file output be in my screenshots folder every time. Can I make `scrot` always output in `~/Pictures/Screenshots/`, so that

```
scrot
```

will just automagically dump the files in that directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put this line in `~/.bash_aliases`. You may need to close the terminal and reopen it for the new alias to function:

```
alias myscrot='scrot ~/Pictures/Screenshots/%b%d::%H%M%S.png'
```

- This will create a file like `May15::110346.png` in `~/Pictures/Screenshots`
- You can use some other way of timestamping your screenshot but I like this. See `man scrot` and `man date` for more options.
- I purposely used `myscrot` so that the original `scrot` is still functional but you can use just `scrot` if you wish!